# Value filled by GetElementByID is not taking by Textfield

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, appium-ios

Hi I am automating one of mobile application in appium. For some reason I am unable to edit a text using .sendkeys method. So, switched to Java script method like below.

```
 driver.executeScript("document.getElementById('first-name').value = \"test\"");
```

Above command fills the text field as expected. However, on submitting final submit button in the form says "First Name" not entered. So value entered not considered.

EX: [image]

any idea whats wrong here..

Thanks

Comment: Can you share `HTML` for the `form`?

Comment: <input id="first-name" name="first" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-pattern ng-valid-minlength ng-valid-maxlength" ng-model="SESSION.YOUR_INFO.firstName" required="" ng-minlength="1" af-alpha-special-chars-only="" maxlength="30" aria-describedby="formatcue-first-name" ng-pattern="/^([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\'\-\s]{0,})$/" ng-disabled="SESSION.isCustomer" aria-invalid="true" type="text">

Comment: Above is html code for one of textbox

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so familiar with appium but try to use value = "'test'" instead of

*value = \"test\"")* it seems to be a " to little.

Comment: Nope...Its just a string illustration. Not works...:(

Answer (score 0):

Some how found a solution below:

```
              WebElement firstName = driver.findElementByXPath("//*[@id=\"first-name\"]");
              driver.executeScript("var element=arguments[0]; "
                          + "element.value='test';"
                          + "if (\"createEvent\" in document) "
                          + "{var evt = document.createEvent(\"HTMLEvents\");"
                          + "evt.initEvent(\"change\", false, true);"
                          + "arguments[0].dispatchEvent(evt);}"
                          + "else"
                          + "arguments[0].fireEvent(\"onchange\");", firstName);
```